# Calling the next() operation on an iterator twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, combinatorics

### **Background:**

I am trying to write code that will identify symmetric partitions. I have a partition, and reverse partition function that will print out the partitions in order, and in reverse

i.e. Partitions of 3: [[3],[2,1],[1,1,1]] and 
     Reverse Partitions of 3: [[1,1,1], [2,1], [3]]

My goal is to write a program that will match the integer in the first position of the sub list of the partitions function (so 3, 2, and 1) and match it with the number of elements in each of the sub list of my reverse partitions (so the code will see [3] and [1,1,1] as the same and count 1 for both.

### **Code**

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def symmetric_function(n):
counter = 0
my_iter = iter(partitions(n))
my_iter2 = iter(lex_partitions(n))
x = 0
size = count(partitions(n))
while x < size:
    if my_iter.__next__()[0] == count(my_iter2.__next__()):
        counter += 1
        x += 1
     -> my_iter = my_iter.__next___()
    else:
        x += 1
     -> my_iter2 = my_iter2.___next___()
print(counter)
```

I put pointers where I'm having trouble. I know this part is wrong but I'm not sure what to do. 
In my if statement I was trying to get the first integer in the first list of my partitions and compare it to the number of elements in the first list of my reverse partitions. Then I want to move on to the next element in my partition list

### **My Question:**

---

If I am already calling the next operation on my iterator, how do I do it again to ensure I go through each element in my list while ensuring that I just get the first integer in my sublist?

Comment: Note: You should never call methods whose names start with `__`. Instead of `my_iter.__next___()`, call `next(my_iter)`.

Comment: calling __next__() advances the iterators and returns the value (or Stop iteration) - so the first time through your loop your replace either my_iter or my_iter2 with the next VALUE.
It is prefered to call next() rather than __next__()

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the next() method! Unfortunately I get a 'list' object is not an iterator error when I insert that into next(my_iter). I'm not quite sure why this is, I declared my list to be an iterator up above.